# Remove a Plugin function through theme's function.php?

Tags: functions

I am using a Plugin called PixGridder for backend setup, but i dont want the front-end css to apply.. I found that in the plugins functions.php has these lines:

```
public function front_styles() {
        $theme_style = get_stylesheet_directory().'/gridder.css';
        if (file_exists($theme_style)) {
            wp_enqueue_style( $this->plugin_slug, get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/gridder.css', array(), $this->version );
        } else {
            wp_enqueue_style( $this->plugin_slug, PIXGRIDDER_URL.'css/front-gridder.css', array(), $this->version );
        }
    }


    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( &$this, 'front_styles' ) );
```

My question is, how do i unregister this function? or at least prevent the plugin from looking for the front styles though my Theme functions? - and is it even possible to unregister a function through a theme?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same way you would remove it from anywhere else, be it a plugin or theme or whatever.

```
add_action('plugins_loaded','remove_whatever');
function remove_whatever() {
    if (class_exists('PixGridder')) {
        remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( PixGridder::get_instance(), 'front_styles' ) );
    }
}
```

Might want to use a better function name than "remove_whatever" though. :)

Answer (score 0):

if the **plugins_loaded** is not working then use **init**

```
add_action('init','remove_plugin_style');
function remove_plugin_style() {
    if (class_exists('Gravity_Forms_Live_Validation')) {
        remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( Gravity_Forms_Live_Validation::get_instance(), 'enqueue_styles' ) );
    }
}
```

its also working fine for me :)